# RadioButton comes checked automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

I used RadioButtonFor like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content, Model.Content, new { @name = "rb", @class = "answer-radio", @id = "answer-" + Model.Counter,@checked = "false" })
    @Html.Label(Model.Content, new { @for = "answer-" + Model.Counter })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Content)
```

But this radiobutton comes "checked". How can i disable it ?

Comment: What value does the property in the model have? If it's `true` then I'm pretty sure that that will override the `@checked = "false"`

Comment: @ChrisF it have just text. and checked="false" stands in properties but it has no effect.

Comment: can you update the question to include the model class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want a radio button? Seems like you might be after a Checkbox...

For a boolean, I would set up a 2 radiobuttons like so:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content, true, new { @id = "rb1" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content, false, new { @id = "rb2" })
```

The html helper will figure out which one to check. If `Model.Content` is of another type, use different values for the radiobuttons and MVC will still figure out which one to check.

Edit:

Actually, it's even simpler than that. If the you use the Html helper `RadioButtonFor` method, it will check the radiobutton if it finds a value that matches the Model property. So you've specified your RadioButton as **always** having the same value as your Model property so it will **always** be checked (and that is the value that will be posted back in the form)

So, if you wanted a bool to default to false, and only return true if checked you could do just this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content, true, new { @id = "rb1" })
```

where `Content` is originally set to false.

You can do it with other value types as well. e.g. if Content was a string, initially set to null, this would post back `"RadioButtonChecked"` only if the radio button was checked. Null otherwise:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content, "RadioButtonChecked", new { @id = "rb1" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "checked" to the attribute list will make it checked no matter what. I would make sure the value in your model is either null or false.